# Error with path of Compact Database .sdf in the client computer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I want to publish my project with compact database but I have an error message that says: the path is not exists, I solved it by write this code:

```
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.sdf");
```

but I don't have result, I mean no delete no select no insert etc..
this my delete code:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("delete from tab ", connection);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

Comment: Have you set up the ``AppDomain.SetData`` method?
Where is the sdf file location?

Comment: Please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13313075/22437), then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26305361/edit) your question to describe every step you took that let you to conclude that you “don't have result”.